# Any difference between "await Task.Run(); return;" and "return Task.Run()"?

Tags: c#, async-await

Is there any conceptual difference between the following two pieces of code:

```
async Task TestAsync() 
{
    await Task.Run(() => DoSomeWork());
}
```

and

```
Task TestAsync() 
{
    return Task.Run(() => DoSomeWork());
}
```

Does the generated code differ, either?

**EDIT:** To avoid confusion with `Task.Run`, a similar case:

```
async Task TestAsync() 
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

and

```
Task TestAsync() 
{
    return Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

**LATE UPDATE:** In addition to the accepted answer, there is also a difference in how `LocalCallContext` gets handled: [CallContext.LogicalGetData gets restored even where there is no asynchrony. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31408515/2674222)

Comment: Yes, it differs. And it differs a lot. otherwise there would be no point in using `await`/`async` at all :)

Comment: I think there are *two* questions here. **1.** Does the actual implementation of the method matter to its caller? **2.** Do the compiled representations of the two methods differ?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

One major difference is in **exception propagation.**  An exception, thrown inside an `async Task` method, gets stored in the returned `Task` object and remains dormant until the task gets observed via `await task`, `task.Wait()`, `task.Result` or `task.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`. It is propagated this way even if thrown from the *synchronous* part of the `async` method.

Consider the following code, where `OneTestAsync` and `AnotherTestAsync` behave quite differently:

```
static async Task OneTestAsync(int n)
{
    await Task.Delay(n);
}

static Task AnotherTestAsync(int n)
{
    return Task.Delay(n);
}

// call DoTestAsync with either OneTestAsync or AnotherTestAsync as whatTest
static void DoTestAsync(Func<int, Task> whatTest, int n)
{
    Task task = null;
    try
    {
        // start the task
        task = whatTest(n);

        // do some other stuff, 
        // while the task is pending
        Console.Write("Press enter to continue");
        Console.ReadLine();
        task.Wait();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.Write("Error: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

If I call `DoTestAsync(OneTestAsync, -2)`, it produces the following output:

```
Press enter to continue
Error: One or more errors occurred.await Task.Delay
Error: 2nd
```

Note, I had to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to see it.

Now, if I call `DoTestAsync(AnotherTestAsync, -2)`, the code workflow inside `DoTestAsync` is quite different, and so is the output. This time, I wasn't asked to press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
Error: The value needs to be either -1 (signifying an infinite timeout), 0 or a positive integer.
Parameter name: millisecondsDelayError: 1st
```

In both cases `Task.Delay(-2)` throws at the beginning, while validating its parameters. This might be a made-up scenario, but in theory `Task.Delay(1000)` may throw too, e.g., when the underlying system timer API fails.

On a side note, the error propagation logic is yet different for **`async void` methods** (as opposed to `async Task` methods). An exception raised inside an `async void` method will be immediately re-thrown on the the current thread's synchronization context (via `SynchronizationContext.Post`), if the current thread has one (`SynchronizationContext.Current != null)`. Otherwise, it will be re-thrown via `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`). The caller doesn't have a chance to handle this exception on the same stack frame.

I posted some more details about TPL exception handling behaviour [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22395161/1768303) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22725349/1768303).

---

**Q**: Is it possible to mimic the exception propagation behavior of `async` methods for non-async `Task`-based methods, so that the latter doesn't throw on the same stack frame?

**A**: If really needed, then yes, there is a trick for that:

```
// async
async Task<int> MethodAsync(int arg)
{
    if (arg < 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("arg");
    // ...
    return 42 + arg;
}

// non-async
Task<int> MethodAsync(int arg)
{
    var task = new Task<int>(() => 
    {
        if (arg < 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("arg");
        // ...
        return 42 + arg;
    });

    task.RunSynchronously(TaskScheduler.Default);
    return task;
}
```

Note however, [under certain conditions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/07/10265067.aspx) (like when it's too deep on the stack), `RunSynchronously` could still execute asynchronously.

---

Another notable difference is that **the `async`/`await` version is more prone to dead-locking on a non-default synchronization context**. E.g., the following will dead-lock in a WinForms or WPF application:

```
static async Task TestAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}

void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TestAsync().Wait(); // dead-lock here
}
```

Change it to a non-async version and it won't dead-lock:

```
Task TestAsync() 
{
    return Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

The nature of the dead-lock is well explained by Stephen Cleary in his [blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Comment: I believe the deadlock in the first example could be avoided by adding .ConfigureAwait(false) to the await line, as it only happens because the method is trying to return to the same execution context. So then the exeptions are the only difference that remains.

Comment: @relatively_random, your comment is correct, although the answer was about the difference between `return Task.Run()` and `await Task.Run(); return`, rather than `await Task.Run().ConfigureAwait(false); return`

Comment: If you find the program closes after you hit Enter, make sure you do ctrl+F5 instead of F5.

Answer (score 54):

> What is the difference between
>
> ```
> async Task TestAsync() 
> {
>     await Task.Delay(1000);
> }
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> Task TestAsync() 
> {
>     return Task.Delay(1000);
> }
> ```
>
> ?

I am confused by this question. Let me try to clarify by responding to your question with another question. What's the difference between?

```
Func<int> MakeFunction()
{
    Func<int> f = ()=>1;
    return ()=>f();
}
```

and

```
Func<int> MakeFunction()
{
    return ()=>1;
}
```

?

Whatever the difference between my two things is, the same difference is between your two things.

Comment: Of course! You've opened my eyes :) In the first case, I create a wrapper task, semantically close to `Task.Delay(1000).ContinueWith(() = {})`. In the second one, it's just `Task.Delay(1000)`. The difference is somewhat subtle, but significant.

Comment: Could you explain a bit the difference ? actually i don't..Thank you

Comment: Given there is a subtle difference with sync contexts, and exception propagation I'd say the difference between async/await and function wrappers is not the same.

Comment: @CameronMacFarland: That's why I asked for clarification. The question asks is there a **conceptual difference** between the two. Well, I don't know. There certainly are many differences; do any of them count as "conceptual" differences? In my example with nested funcs there are also differences in error propagation; if the functions are closed over local state there are differences in local lifetimes, and so on.  Are these "conceptual" differences?

Comment: When i look at your answer, actually it's a question in response to a question, I would conclude that both do the same, but the first `MakeFunction` is complicating things :-)

Comment: This is an old answer, but I believe given today, would have been downvoted. It does not answer the question, nor does it point the OP to a source from which he can learn.

Comment: @DanielDubovski: And yet, the original poster commented "Of course! You've opened my eyes. The difference is somewhat subtle, but significant". It sounds like the OP got a significant insight from the answer, which is why I gave it.  You are of course free to downvote this answer which plainly helped the OP if you believe that it is not helpful, but what would be even better is if you would leave an answer of your own that models what you consider to be an ideal answer. That way we all learn from your wisdom.

Comment: It might have helped the OP, but this is a community website and personally I didn't get the point at all

Comment: @MickaelV.: The OP asked -- ten years ago -- what the difference is between two asynchronous workflows. This is a vague question; I don't know what differences the OP considers relevant or important. Are they asking whether the difference is semantic? Or stylistic? Or what memory is allocated?  I could list differences all day.  But often in these sorts of questions, the real issue is that the asynchronous workflow itself is what is confusing to the original poster. I therefore made two program fragments that illustrated the same concepts without asynchrony.

Comment: @MickaelV.: By understanding what the OP considers a "relevant difference" between two simple synchronous workflows, we can understand what the OP considers a relevant difference between two asynchronous workflows.

Comment: @MickaelV.: Though I wanted the example to prompt the OP to make the question less vague, I also had an ulterior motive!  By encouraging the OP to reflect on what makes two synchronous workflows "different", I hoped they would then be able to make the logical leap to answer the same question about asynchronous workflows *for themselves* by reason alone. Learning to reason about your own code is a valuable skill and modern programming languages do not make it as easy as perhaps they ought to. As you can see by the first comment, my ulterior motive was achieved.

Comment: @MickaelV.: I hope that explains the point of this answer to your satisfaction!

Answer (score 12):

The two examples *do* differ. When a method is marked with the `async` keyword, the compiler generates a state-machine behind the scenes. This is what is responsible for resuming continuations once an awaitable has been awaited.

In contrast, when a method is *not* marked with `async` you are losing the ability to `await` awaitables. (That is, within the method itself; the method can still be awaited by its caller.) However, by avoiding the `async` keyword, you are no longer generating the state-machine, which can add a fair bit of overhead (lifting locals to fields of the state-machine, additional objects to the GC).

In examples like this, if you are able to avoid `async-await` and return an awaitable directly, it should be done to improve the efficiency of the method.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19098143/921321) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19098209/921321) which are very similar to your question and this answer.

Answer (score 12):

1. The first method does not even compile.

   > Since '`Program.TestAsync()`' is an async method that returns '`Task`', a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression. Did you intend to return '`Task<T>`'?

   It has to be

   ```
   async Task TestAsync()
   {
       await Task.Run(() => DoSomeWork());
   }
   ```
2. There is major conceptual difference between these two. The first one is asynchronous, the second one is not. [Read Async Performance: Understanding the Costs of Async and Await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456402.aspx) to get a little more about internals of `async`/`await`.
3. They do generate different code.

   ```
   .method private hidebysig 
       instance class [mscorlib]System.Threading.Tasks.Task TestAsync () cil managed 
   {
       .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncStateMachineAttribute::.ctor(class [mscorlib]System.Type) = (
           01 00 25 53 4f 54 65 73 74 50 72 6f 6a 65 63 74
           2e 50 72 6f 67 72 61 6d 2b 3c 54 65 73 74 41 73
           79 6e 63 3e 64 5f 5f 31 00 00
       )
       .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute::.ctor() = (
           01 00 00 00
       )
       // Method begins at RVA 0x216c
       // Code size 62 (0x3e)
       .maxstack 2
       .locals init (
           [0] valuetype SOTestProject.Program/'<TestAsync>d__1',
           [1] class [mscorlib]System.Threading.Tasks.Task,
           [2] valuetype [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder
       )

       IL_0000: ldloca.s 0
       IL_0002: ldarg.0
       IL_0003: stfld class SOTestProject.Program SOTestProject.Program/'<TestAsync>d__1'::'<>4__this'
       IL_0008: ldloca.s 0
       IL_000a: call valuetype [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder::Create()
       IL_000f: stfld valuetype [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder SOTestProject.Program/'<TestAsync>d__1'::'<>t__builder'
       IL_0014: ldloca.s 0
       IL_0016: ldc.i4.m1
       IL_0017: stfld int32 SOTestProject.Program/'<TestAsync>d__1'::'<>1__state'
       IL_001c: ldloca.s 0
       IL_001e: ldfld valuetype [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder SOTestProject.Program/'<TestAsync>d__1'::'<>t__builder'
       IL_0023: stloc.2
       IL_0024: ldloca.s 2
       IL_0026: ldloca.s 0
       IL_0028: call instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder::Start<valuetype SOTestProject.Program/'<TestAsync>d__1'>(!!0&)
       IL_002d: ldloca.s 0
       IL_002f: ldflda valuetype [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder SOTestProject.Program/'<TestAsync>d__1'::'<>t__builder'
       IL_0034: call instance class [mscorlib]System.Threading.Tasks.Task [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder::get_Task()
       IL_0039: stloc.1
       IL_003a: br.s IL_003c

       IL_003c: ldloc.1
       IL_003d: ret
   } // end of method Program::TestAsync
   ```

   and

   ```
   .method private hidebysig 
       instance class [mscorlib]System.Threading.Tasks.Task TestAsync2 () cil managed 
   {
       // Method begins at RVA 0x21d8
       // Code size 23 (0x17)
       .maxstack 2
       .locals init (
           [0] class [mscorlib]System.Threading.Tasks.Task CS$1$0000
       )

       IL_0000: nop
       IL_0001: ldarg.0
       IL_0002: ldftn instance class [mscorlib]System.Threading.Tasks.Task SOTestProject.Program::'<TestAsync2>b__4'()
       IL_0008: newobj instance void class [mscorlib]System.Func`1<class [mscorlib]System.Threading.Tasks.Task>::.ctor(object, native int)
       IL_000d: call class [mscorlib]System.Threading.Tasks.Task [mscorlib]System.Threading.Tasks.Task::Run(class [mscorlib]System.Func`1<class [mscorlib]System.Threading.Tasks.Task>)
       IL_0012: stloc.0
       IL_0013: br.s IL_0015

       IL_0015: ldloc.0
       IL_0016: ret
   } // end of method Program::TestAsync2
   ```

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek, indeed it didn't compile. That was a typo, I am sure you got it right. Otherwise, a great answer, thanks! I thought C# might be smart enough to avoid generating a state machine class in the first case.