# Return await fooAsync() or return fooAsync() inside a method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

Suppose I have a method called `fooAsync()`:

```
public Task<T> FooAsync<T>(T foo, T bar)
{
    // do some stuff
    var returnFoo = await netLibraryMethodAsync(x, y, z);
    // do some more stuff
    return returnFoo as T;
}
```

Now I have an awaiter method that does only one thing `call fooAsync()`.

```
public Task<string> BarAsync(string foo, string bar)
{
    return this.FooAsync(foo, bar);
}
```

My  question here is that: inside BarAsync, should I use `return await this.FooAsync()` or `return this.FooAsync()` and why?

I have tried looking around but haven't found a conclusive answer for this pattern.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @JohnSaunders: Understood sir.

Comment: Wouldn't return await FooAsync(foo, bar); have return type T?

Comment: @bit: Yeah, it was a quick sample. But the question remains valid :)

Comment: I think you should return this.FooAsync(foo, bar); and leave it upto the caller, whether to await or not.

Comment: They are basically the same (unless there are other awaits in your BarAsync before the call to FooAsync).

Comment: also possible duplicate of [Any difference between “await Task.Run(); return;” and “return Task.Run()”?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21033150/1768303)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question here is that: inside BarAsync, should I use return await this.FooAsync() or return this.FooAsync() and why?

You should use `return FooAsync(foo, bar)`. In this case, you're not doing anything other than calling another asynchronous method, so by avoiding `async` and `await`, you're avoiding a small amount of overhead.

Comment: I have bumped into so many articles of yours in my quest of understanding async/await :)

Also, we should also mention this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456402.aspx