# Difference between Task and async Task

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task

C# provides two ways of creating asynchronous methods:

**`Task()`:**

```cs
static Task<string> MyAsyncTPL() {
  Task<string> result = PerformWork();
  return result.ContinueWith(t => MyContinuation());
}
```

**`async Task()`:**

```cs
static async Task<string> MyAsync() {
  string result = await PerformWork();
  return MyContinuation();
}
```

Both of the above methods are `async` and achieve the same thing. So, when should I choose one method over the other? Are there any guidelines or advantages of using one over the other?

Comment: Your examples aren't the same - they behave differently if the task returned from `PerformWork` fails or is cancelled.

Comment: Or if there's a current `SynchronizationContext`. Or if the returned task is used as a parent task. Or probably a few other obscure corner cases that `await` handles more decently than `ContinueWith`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any difference between "await Task.Run(); return;" and "return Task.Run()"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21033150/any-difference-between-await-task-run-return-and-return-task-run)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I recommend you use `await` rather than `ContinueWith`. While - at a high level - they are very similar, they also have different default behavior.

When you use `ContinueWith`, you are choosing a lower-level abstraction. In particular, here are some "danger points", and this is why I don't recommend using `ContinueWith` unless the method is *really simple* (or your name is Stephen Toub):

- Exceptions raised from `async Task` methods are placed on the returned task; exceptions raised from non-`async` methods are propagated directly.
- `await` will by default will resume the `async` method in the same "context". This "context" is `SynchronizationContext.Current` unless it is `null`, in which case it is `TaskScheduler.Current`. This means that if you call `MyAsync` on a UI thread (or within an ASP.NET request context), then `MyContinuation` will also execute on the UI thread (or in that same ASP.NET request context). I explain this more [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).
- You should always specify a scheduler for `ContinueWith`; otherwise, it will pick up `TaskScheduler.Current`, which can cause surprising behavior. I describe this problem in detail [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html). That post is about `StartNew`; but `ContinueWith` has the same "non-default default scheduler" problem described in that post.
- `await` uses appropriate behavior and optimization flags that are not set by default in `ContinueWith`. For example, it uses `DenyChildAttach` (to ensure asynchronous tasks are not mistakenly used as parallel tasks) and `ExecuteSynchronously` (an optimization).

In short, the only reason to use `ContinueWith` for asynchronous tasks is to save an *extremely* small amount of time and memory (by avoiding the `async` state machine overhead), and in exchange your code is less readable and maintainable.

With an extremely simple example, you might get away with it; but as Jon Skeet pointed out, as soon as you have loops the `ContinueWith` code simply explodes in complexity.

Answer (score 10):

`await` is basically a shorthand for the continuation, by default using the same synchronization context for the continuation.

For very simple examples like yours, there's not *much* benefit in using `await` - although the wrapping and unwrapping of exceptions makes for a more consistent approach.

When you've got more complicated code, however, `async` makes a *huge* difference. Imagine you wanted:

```
static async Task<List<string>> MyAsync() {
    List<string> results = new List<string>();
    // One at a time, but each asynchronously...
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        // Or use LINQ, with rather a lot of care :)
        results.Add(await SomeMethodReturningString(i));
    }
    return results;
}
```

... that gets much hairier with manual continuations.

Additionally, `async`/`await` can work with types other than `Task`/`Task<T>` so long as they implement the appropriate pattern.

It's worth reading up more about what it's doing behind the scenes. You might want to start with [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx).