# Difference between method returning Task and async Task

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have written below two methods

```
    private Task<string> GetStringTask(string url)
    {
        var client = new WebClient();
        var task = client.DownloadDataTaskAsync(new Uri(url));

        var task2 = task.ContinueWith<string>(task1 =>
        {
            var str = Encoding.Default.GetString(task1.Result);
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            return str;
        });

        return task2;
    }

    private async Task<string> GetStringAsyc(string url)
    {
        var client = new WebClient();
        var htmlByte = await client.DownloadDataTaskAsync(new Uri(url));
        var task2 = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var str = Encoding.Default.GetString(htmlByte);
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            return str;
        });

        return task2;
    }
```

I can invoke the both the methods inside the another async method same way like below

```
var mystring = await GetStringTask("http://www.microsoft.com");

var mystring1 = await GetStringAsync("http://www.microsoft.com");
```

Both method return the same result. Can anyone explain me the difference between these two methods.

Comment: look at this.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22997523/difference-between-task-and-async

Answer (score 1):

`async` modifier just determines that you can use `await` keyword in your function body.

from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9225932/1095390) answer:

> It was introduced mainly to avoid backward compatibility issues. If
>   the async-ness of a method must be inferred by the compiler (that
>   would be through the detection of await keywords), then there are
>   subtle scenarios where existing code would suddenly be treated
>   differently, notably when you have identifiers (variable or function
>   names called await).