# Async/Await Execution Difference

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to get a good grasp of async/await and I want to clear some of the confusion. Can someone please explain what would be the difference in terms of execution for the following:

```
// version 1
public Task Copy(string source, string destination) {
    return Task.Run(() => File.Copy(source, destination));
}

public async Task Test() {
    await Copy("test", "test2");    
    // do other stuff
}
```

And:

```
// version 2
public async Task Copy(string source, string destination) {
    await Task.Run(() => File.Copy(source, destination));
}

public async Task Test() {
    await Copy("test", "test2");
    // ...
}
```

Are they resulting in the same code and why would I write one over the other ?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21033150/1768303

Comment: @Noseratio Yep, it is indeed, also Erics  answer is an "eye-opener", sorry for the dup, didn't find anything (not really sure how to formulate the search :P)

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov, IMO, besides the state machine's overhead, the most principal difference is the [exception propagation logic](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21082631/1768303).

Comment: @Noseratio Thanks! Superb answer (the one you linked). This helps a lot !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of let me start with the point that both codes are **not** same.

Your version1 code will create only one "State machine" as it contains await in `Test` method only.

Your version2 code will create two "state machines" for `Copy` and `Test` method which adds some overhead.

Why do we use `async` methods? Simple just to make our code readable, elegant while dealing with "Asynchronous Tasks". It makes our code better avoiding callbacks and continuations etc.

> Let's break down what `Copy` method is doing and we answer the
>   question whether we really need it to be `async`?

`Copy` method simply delegates the call to `Task.Run` which returns a task that eventually reaches completion on `File.Copy`'s completion. So the intent is clear here we need a task which notifies `File.Copy` completion. This method does all what you need, no need for it to be `async` to work as expected.

> So, When do you need `async`?

You need async when you need to execute some code upon earlier task's completion(Continuation).

Example:

```
public async Task Test() 
{
    await Copy("test", "test2");
    DoPostCopied(whatever);
    await DoPostCopied2();//Etc
}
```

You can verify this difference between `async` and non async method just by decompiling both versions. It is too long and won't be readable so I skipped posting it here.

Conclusion: Use `async` only when **required**. In this case version1 is better and you should prefer it over version2.

Comment: @AmitJoki I suppose we need to give +1 for op as well for interesting question

Comment: Thanks, it's clear ! :) So basically async only when you *must*

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov Yes, that's the thing. [Bonus reading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456402.aspx) about async await overhead :)