# Why does the async keyword generate an enumerator & additional struct when compiled?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, compiler-construction, ndepend

If I create a simple class like the following:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public Task TestMethod(int someParameter)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(someParameter);
    }

    public async Task TestMethod(bool someParameter)
    {
        await Task.FromResult(someParameter);
    }
}
```

and examine it within NDepend, it shows that the `TestMethod` taking a bool and being `async Task` has a struct generated for it with an enumerator, the enumerator state machine and some additional stuff.

[image]

Why does the compiler generate a struct called `TestClass+<TestMethod>d__0` with an enumerator for the async method?

It seems to generate more IL than what the actual method produces. In this example, the compiler generates 35 lines of IL for my class, while it generates 81 lines of IL for the struct. It's also increasing the complexity of the compiled code and causing NDepend to flag it for several rule violations.

Comment: The code in async/await is based on [Jeff Richter's Async Enumerator pattern](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Charles/Jeffrey-Richter-and-his-AsyncEnumerator). There is already a voice suggesting a fix for this https://ndepend.uservoice.com/forums/226344-ndepend-user-voice/suggestions/6375659-exclude-compiler-generated-code-by-default.

Comment: Because that's how async/await works. What you see is the [implementation detail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456402.aspx) of the feature.

Comment: This really underlines the importance of making sure you're not blindly using async all over the place when it's not needed. That's more overhead than what I guess I was expecting.

Comment: @JohnathonSullinger Use async [only when you need it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23180947/2530848).

Comment: @Aron: I could be wrong, but I don't think `async` is based on Async Enumerator. While they appear similar at first glance, `async` is capable of much more complex transformations.

Comment: @StephenCleary much much much more complex yes. But creating an enumerator to store state of a function between yielding control back to the caller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the `async` and `await` keywords are just syntactical sugar for something called [coroutines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine).

There are no special IL instructions to support the creation of asynchronous methods. Instead, an async method can be seen as kind of a state machine somehow.

I will try to make this example as short as possible:

```
[TestClass]
public class AsyncTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task RunTest_1()
    {
        var result = await GetStringAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }

    private async Task AppendLineAsync(StringBuilder builder, string text)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        builder.AppendLine(text);
    }

    public async Task<string> GetStringAsync()
    {
        // Code before first await
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        var secondLine = "Second Line";

        // First await
        await AppendLineAsync(builder, "First Line");

        // Inner synchronous code
        builder.AppendLine(secondLine);

        // Second await
        await AppendLineAsync(builder, "Third Line");

        // Return
        return builder.ToString();
    }
}
```

This is some async code as you've probably become used to: Our `GetStringAsync` method at first creates a `StringBuilder` synchronously, then it awaits some asynchronous methods and finally it returns the result. How would this be implemented if there was no `await` keyword?

Add the following code to the `AsyncTest` class:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task RunTest_2()
{
    var result = await GetStringAsyncWithoutAwait();
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}

public Task<string> GetStringAsyncWithoutAwait()
{
    // Code before first await
    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    var secondLine = "Second Line";

    return new StateMachine(this, builder, secondLine).CreateTask();
}

private class StateMachine
{
    private readonly AsyncTest instance;
    private readonly StringBuilder builder;
    private readonly string secondLine;
    private readonly TaskCompletionSource<string> completionSource;

    private int state = 0;

    public StateMachine(AsyncTest instance, StringBuilder builder, string secondLine)
    {
        this.instance = instance;
        this.builder = builder;
        this.secondLine = secondLine;
        this.completionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
    }

    public Task<string> CreateTask()
    {
        DoWork();
        return this.completionSource.Task;
    }

    private void DoWork()
    {
        switch (this.state)
        {
            case 0:
                goto state_0;
            case 1:
                goto state_1;
            case 2:
                goto state_2;
        }

        state_0:
            this.state = 1;

            // First await
            var firstAwaiter = this.instance.AppendLineAsync(builder, "First Line")
                                        .GetAwaiter();
            firstAwaiter.OnCompleted(DoWork);
            return;

        state_1:
            this.state = 2;

            // Inner synchronous code
            this.builder.AppendLine(this.secondLine);

            // Second await
            var secondAwaiter = this.instance.AppendLineAsync(builder, "Third Line")
                                            .GetAwaiter();
            secondAwaiter.OnCompleted(DoWork);
            return;

        state_2:
            // Return
            var result = this.builder.ToString();
            this.completionSource.SetResult(result);
    }
}
```

So obviously the code before the first `await` keyword just stays the same. Everything else is converted to a state machine which uses `goto` statements to execute your previous code piecewise. Every time one of the awaited tasks is completed, the state machine advances to the next step.

This example is oversimplified to clarify what happens behind the scenes. Add error handling and some `foreach`-Loops in your async method, and the state machine gets much more complex.

By the way, there is another construct in C# that does such a thing: the `yield` keyword. This also generates a state machine and the code looks quite similar to what `await` produces.

For further reading, look into [this CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/535635/Async-Await-and-the-Generated-StateMachine) which takes a deeper look into the generated state machine.

Comment: Thanks for the details answer, this really helped make it clear. I will be sure to check out the link as well

Comment: In this example, your DoWork() method is a simplified variation of .MoveNext() in the async state machine right?

Comment: That's right. Minus optimization, cancellation, exception handling, internal framework methods.

Answer (score 3):

The original code generation for `async` was closely related to that of enumerator blocks, so they started off using the same code in the compiler for those two code transformations. It has changed quite a bit since then, but it still has some holdovers from the original design (such as the name `MoveNext`).

For more about the compiler-generated parts, [Jon Skeet's blog series](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jonskeet/2011/05/08/eduasync-part-1-introduction/) is the best source.

Comment: Alternate (newer) link, in case the old one breaks at some point: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/05/08/eduasync-part-1-introduction/