# Await for result or return task directly?

Tags: c#, async-await

Is there any difference between returning task directly and awaiting for result first and then return result?

```
public Task<Result> GetResultAsync()
{
    return ComposeResultAsync(); // returning task directly
}

private Task<Result> ComposeResultAsync()
{
    // async code
}
```

versus

```
public async Task<Result> GetResultAsync()
{
    return await ComposeResultAsync(); // awaiting result first
}

private Task<Result> ComposeResultAsync()
{
    // async code
}
```

Is there any reason to use the first one example, unless I need to await another task?

```
public async Task<Result> GetResultAsync()
{
    await DoSomethingElseAsync();

    return await ComposeResultAsync();
}
```

I am still not sure.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21033150/any-difference-between-await-task-run-return-and-return-task-run

Comment: What if you need an answer after some time, and you want to run two tasks parallel? than it is better not to wait, but let him work parallel, and get wait when you really need answer