# Proper way to implement methods that return Task<T>

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library, task

For simplicity let's imagine we have a method that should return an object while doing some heavy operation. There're two ways to implement:

```
public Task<object> Foo()
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // some heavy synchronous stuff.

        return new object();
    }
}
```

And

```
public async Task<object> Foo()
{
    return await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // some heavy stuff
        return new object();
    }
}
```

After examining generated IL there're two completely different things generated:

```
.method public hidebysig 
    instance class [mscorlib]System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<object> Foo () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
    // Code size 42 (0x2a)
    .maxstack 2
    .locals init (
        [0] class [mscorlib]System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<object>
    )

    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: ldsfld class [mscorlib]System.Func`1<object> AsyncTest.Class1/'<>c'::'<>9__0_0'
    IL_0006: dup
    IL_0007: brtrue.s IL_0020

    IL_0009: pop
    IL_000a: ldsfld class AsyncTest.Class1/'<>c' AsyncTest.Class1/'<>c'::'<>9'
    IL_000f: ldftn instance object AsyncTest.Class1/'<>c'::'<Foo>b__0_0'()
    IL_0015: newobj instance void class [mscorlib]System.Func`1<object>::.ctor(object, native int)
    IL_001a: dup
    IL_001b: stsfld class [mscorlib]System.Func`1<object> AsyncTest.Class1/'<>c'::'<>9__0_0'

    IL_0020: call class [mscorlib]System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<!!0> [mscorlib]System.Threading.Tasks.Task::Run<object>(class [mscorlib]System.Func`1<!!0>)
    IL_0025: stloc.0
    IL_0026: br.s IL_0028

    IL_0028: ldloc.0
    IL_0029: ret
}
```

And

```
.method public hidebysig 
    instance class [mscorlib]System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<object> Foo () cil managed 
{
    .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncStateMachineAttribute::.ctor(class [mscorlib]System.Type) = (
        01 00 1a 41 73 79 6e 63 54 65 73 74 2e 43 6c 61
        73 73 31 2b 3c 42 61 72 3e 64 5f 5f 31 00 00
    )
    .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute::.ctor() = (
        01 00 00 00
    )
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2088
    // Code size 59 (0x3b)
    .maxstack 2
    .locals init (
        [0] class AsyncTest.Class1/'<Foo>d__1',
        [1] valuetype [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1<object>
    )

    IL_0000: newobj instance void AsyncTest.Class1/'<Foo>d__1'::.ctor()
    IL_0005: stloc.0
    IL_0006: ldloc.0
    IL_0007: ldarg.0
    IL_0008: stfld class AsyncTest.Class1 AsyncTest.Class1/'<Foo>d__1'::'<>4__this'
    IL_000d: ldloc.0
    IL_000e: call valuetype [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1<!0> valuetype [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1<object>::Create()
    IL_0013: stfld valuetype [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1<object> AsyncTest.Class1/'<Foo>d__1'::'<>t__builder'
    IL_0018: ldloc.0
    IL_0019: ldc.i4.m1
    IL_001a: stfld int32 AsyncTest.Class1/'<Foo>d__1'::'<>1__state'
    IL_001f: ldloc.0
    IL_0020: ldfld valuetype [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1<object> AsyncTest.Class1/'<Foo>d__1'::'<>t__builder'
    IL_0025: stloc.1
    IL_0026: ldloca.s 1
    IL_0028: ldloca.s 0
    IL_002a: call instance void valuetype [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1<object>::Start<class AsyncTest.Class1/'<Foo>d__1'>(!!0&)
    IL_002f: ldloc.0
    IL_0030: ldflda valuetype [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1<object> AsyncTest.Class1/'<Foo>d__1'::'<>t__builder'
    IL_0035: call instance class [mscorlib]System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<!0> valuetype [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1<object>::get_Task()
    IL_003a: ret
}
```

As you can see in the first case logic is straightforward, lambda function is created and then call to the `Task.Run` is generated and the result is returned. In the second example instance of `AsyncTaskMethodBuilder` is created and then task is actually built and returned. Since I always expected foo method to be called as `await Foo()` at some higher level, I have always used the first example. However, I see the latter more often. So which approach is correct? What pros and cons do each have?

---

#### Real world example

Let's say we have `UserStore` which has method `Task<User> GetUserByNameAsync(string userName)` which is used inside web api controller like:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> FindUser(string userName)
{
    var user = await _userStore.GetUserByNameAsync(userName);

    if (user == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(user);
}
```

Which implementation of `Task<User> GetUserByNameAsync(string userName)` would be correct?

```
public Task<User> GetUserByNameAsync(string userName)
{
    return _dbContext.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(user => user.UserName == userName);
}
```

or

```
public async Task<User> GetUserNameAsync(string userName)
{
    return await _dbContext.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(user => user.UserName == username);
}
```

Comment: Related: [Any difference between “await Task.Run(); return;” and “return Task.Run()”?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21033150/1768303)

Comment: Downvote? Well, I'd like to at least hear what's wrong with the question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you can see from the IL, `async/await` creates a state machine (and an additional `Task`) even in the case of trivial async tail calls, i.e.

```
return await Task.Run(...);
```

This leads to performance degradation due to additional instructions and allocations. So the rule of thumb is: if your method ends with `await ...` or `return await ...`, and it is the **one and only** `await` statement, then it's *generally* safe to remove the `async` keyword and directly return the `Task` that you were going to await.

One potentially unintended consequence of doing this is that if an exception is thrown inside the returned `Task`, the outer method will not appear in the stack trace.

There's a hidden gotcha in the `return await ...` case too though. If the awaiter is not explicitly configured *not* to continue on captured context via `ConfigureAwait(false)`, then the outer `Task` (the one created for you by the async state machine) cannot transition to completed state until the final postback to the `SynchronizationContext` (captured just before the `await`) has finished. This serves no real purpose but can still result in a deadlock if you block on the outer task for some reason ([here's a detailed explanation](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) of what happens in such case).

Comment: Thanks. Well explained answer. Stacktrace is never worth a performance, imho. Besides that is there any reason why people use trivial async tail calls?

Comment: @Leri, I can't think of any other reason to do this, and I'm not seeing anything in this Roslyn team discussion on making this a compiler optimization moving forward: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/1981

Comment: I see. Well, from this point I think the answer to my question is pretty obvious. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

> So which approach is correct?

Neither.

If you have *synchronous* work to do, then *the API should be synchronous*:

```
public object Foo()
{
    // some heavy synchronous stuff.

    return new object();
}
```

If the calling method can block its thread (i.e., it's an ASP.NET call, or it's running on a thread pool thread), then it just calls it directly:

```
var result = Foo();
```

And if the calling thread can't block it's thread (i.e., it's running on the UI thread), then it can run `Foo` on the thread pool:

```
var result = await Task.Run(() => Foo());
```

As I describe on my blog, [`Task.Run` should be used for invocation, not implementation](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html).

---

> Real World Example

(which is a completely different scenario)

> Which implementation of Task GetUserByNameAsync(string userName) would be correct?

Either one is acceptable. The one with `async` and `await` has some extra overhead, but it won't be noticeable at runtime (assuming the thing you're `await`ing actually does I/O, which is true in the general case).

Note that if there's other code in the method, then the one with `async` and `await` is better. This is a common mistake:

```
Task<string> MyFuncAsync()
{
  using (var client = new HttpClient())
    return client.GetStringAsync("http://www.example.com/");
}
```

In this case, the `HttpClient` is disposed before the task completes.

Another thing to note is that exceptions *before* returning the task are thrown differently:

```
Task<string> MyFuncAsync(int id)
{
  ... // Something that throws InvalidOperationException
  return OtherFuncAsync();
}
```

Since there is no `async`, the exception is *not* placed on the returned task; it is thrown directly. This can confuse the calling code if it does something more complex than just `await`ing the task:

```
var task1 = MyFuncAsync(1); // Exception is thrown here.
var task2 = MyFuncAsync(2);
...
try
{
  await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
}
catch (InvalidOperationException)
{
  // Exception is not caught here. It was thrown at the first line.
}
```

Comment: +1. Well, for the first part of your answer, `Task.Run` was just for demonstration. And for the second part you're totally right if one's application uses exceptions to control application flow. However, I let my exceptions be exceptions i.e. in my current architecture, if exception is thrown means something awfully wrong has happened, so I don't handle them as you've shown.

Comment: You don't use databases and http client and other classes with `using`? Even if you can't handle the exception you still should do proper cleanup @Leri. The second part of this answer is the important one.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum For web development no. I let di scope do that for me.