# "async Task then await Task" vs "Task then return task"

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

In order to get some solid base understanding about asynchronous programming and the `await`, I would like to know what the difference is between these two code snippets when it comes to multi threading and the execution sequence and time:

**This**:

```
public Task CloseApp()
{
        return Task.Run(
                         ()=>{ 
                                // save database
                                // turn off some lights
                                // shutdown application
                          });
}
```

**Versus this:**

```
public async Task CloseApp()
{
        await Task.Run(
                         ()=>{ 
                                // save database
                                // turn off some lights
                                // shutdown application
                          });
}
```

if I am calling it in this routine:

```
private async void closeButtonTask()
{
    // Some Task 1
    // ..

    await CloseApp();
    
    // Some Task 2
    // ..
}
```

Comment: They have subtle differences in how exceptions are wrapped

Comment: Possible dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21033150/any-difference-between-await-task-run-return-and-return-task-run

Comment: closeButtonTask should rather return Task instead of void.

Comment: This [sharplab sample](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLQFEAeAHJzkCWA9gHYBqUCBUwANigD4ACADAARMCMA3ALABQrDpwCsffgKYBmDgCY2AYTYBvAW3UcZTABwcAbGwCCyAJ4kAxoYDuUAjAAUASjYBeAHwcAnEdMWFUWnoIJ3ENNjUNaX0fM3MAJQh4BBInVw9jWP9AiGDHUI0I9VwCADdYCGiMvwCg1Pd9ADoFIgBbbHoYCAATJj1xAF8gA) I put together shows the underlying machinery.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

It is almost the same (in terms of threads etc.). But for the second one (using `await`) a lot more overhead will be created by the compiler.

Methods declared as `async` and using `await` are converted into a *state machine* by the compiler. So when you hit the `await`, the control flow is returned to the calling method and execution of your `async` method is resumed after the `await` when the awaited `Task` has finished.

As there is no more code after your `await`, there is no need to use `await` anyway. Simply return the `Task` is enough.

Comment: *"when you hit the await, the control flow is returned to the calling method"* -- The control flow **might** be returned to the calling method, particularly it won't return when the awaited task is already complete.

Comment: @acelent thx for the detail, never thought about what happens when the task is already finished. I don't know the exact details of what the compiler does line by line.

Comment: I totally dont understand this

Comment: When your task will be finished a thread from Thread Pool will call the `Post` method and notify the caller that the task was finished. As I remember the rest of async method will be executed as `ContinueWith`. Execution will continue from await point, but it can be executed in different thread.

Comment: This blog post explains it very cleanly. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/dissecting-the-async-methods-in-c/

In short, there is some optimization logic to prevent unnecessary waiting.

Answer (score 14):

There are very few differences between the two approaches. Basically, they share the same semantics. However, the version with async/await wraps the execution of the inner task in an outer compiler-generated task. The non-async version does not. Thus, the non-async version is (very marginally) more efficient.

Comment: *"the non-async version is (very marginally) more efficient."* -- That depends, if the method is called very often, then the async/await version might generate noticeable garbage: the state machine and another task.

Comment: @acelent: generating some generation 0 garbage still feels pretty marginal to me

Comment: Ok, I just want to point out that is not always the case for everyone ([1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456402.aspx)), and you can't rely on tasks or references to tasks to be that ephemeral ([2](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/BUILD2011/TOOL-829T), [at 0:25:40](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/BUILD2011/TOOL-829T#time=25m40s), [at 0:30:20](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/BUILD2011/TOOL-829T#time=30m20s)).