# Unable to await SetStringAsync in IDistributedCache

Tags: c#, async-await

I am using .NET Core 2.0 with Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis 2.0. Why is IDistributedCache.SetStringAsync not actually marked as async, and therefore not awaitable?

```
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddDistributedRedisCache(options =>
        {
            options.Configuration = "127.0.0.1";
            options.InstanceName = "master";
        });

        var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

        var cache = provider.GetService<IDistributedCache>();

        // Does not compile
        await cache.SetStringAsync("mykey", "myvalue");
```

Comment: It looks like interface `IDistributedCache` doesn't have that method: https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions/IDistributedCache.cs

Comment: ...but you can do it with this extension https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions/DistributedCacheExtensions.cs ... What does compiler error says? Is method that is awaiting marked with async?

Comment: Are you calling SetStringAsync from an async method?

Comment: Yep, this was my dumb mistake! The problem was my method should be async, not SetStringAsync

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those methods are defined to return `Task` (they are extension methods in [DistributedCacheExtensions](https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions/DistributedCacheExtensions.cs#L99)):

```
 public static Task SetStringAsync(this IDistributedCache cache, string key, string value)
 {
     return cache.SetStringAsync(key, value, new DistributedCacheEntryOptions());
 }
```

And you can use `await` with such kind of method as ([MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/await))

> The task to which the `await` operator is applied typically is returned by a call to a method that implements the Task-Based Asynchronous Pattern. They include methods that return `Task`, `Task<TResult>`, and `System.Threading.Tasks.ValueType<TResult>` objects.

but you cannot use `await` in the method that is not marked as `async`, that's why you have a compilation error:

> await can only be used in an asynchronous method modified by the async keyword.

---

If you are interested in what would have been the difference if the team had marked `SetStringAsync` as async method, like:

```
public static async Task SetStringAsync
```

then look into SO ["async Task then await Task" vs "Task then return task"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38017016/async-task-then-await-task-vs-task-then-return-task)