# Is async lambda needed when passing it to a function that expects Func<Task<T>>?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, lambda, async-await, delegates

I have an executor method:

```
public static async Task<T> ExecuteAsync(Func<Task<T>> method)
{
    await method();
}
```

When calling it both

```
await ExecuteAsync( () => obj.MethodAsync());
```

and

```
await ExecuteAsync( async () => await obj.MethodAsync());
```

seem to work just fine and finish in roughly the same amount of time while spawning roughly the same amount of threads. It was my understanding that in the first case the method will be executed synchronously inside the lambda and the lambda would be executed asynchronously, and in the second example both the method and the lambda would be executed asynchronously.

Comment: Possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38017016/async-task-then-await-task-vs-task-then-return-task

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Any difference between “await Task.Run(); return;” and “return Task.Run()”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21033150/any-difference-between-await-task-run-return-and-return-task-run) TL;DR there is hardly any difference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Any difference between "await Task.Run(); return;" and "return Task.Run()"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21033150/any-difference-between-await-task-run-return-and-return-task-run)

Comment: Relevant: [Eliding async and await](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html).

Comment: Thanks for the references to other questions. I think that the answer I've selected does a good job of reasoning and explaining what's happening in the case when I make the lambda async.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`async` and `await` apply only to method definitions.

`async` means that the compiler will generate a state machine for the method.

`await` means that the compiler will generate code to synchronously wait for the invoke method to complete.

```
ExecuteAsync(() => obj.MethodAsync())
```

translates something to:

```
[CompilerGenerated]
private sealed class <>c__DisplayClass0_0
{
    public C<T> obj;

    internal Task<T> <M>b__0()
    {
        return obj.MethodAsync();
    }
}

// ...

<>c__DisplayClass0_0 <>c__DisplayClass0_ = new <>c__DisplayClass0_0();
<>c__DisplayClass0_.obj = obj;
ExecuteAsync(new Func<Task<T>>(<>c__DisplayClass0_.<M>b__0));
```

On the other hand,

```
ExecuteAsync( async () => await obj.MethodAsync())
```

translates to something more complex involving nested state machines.

Try [sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io) to see the lowered code.

In fact, the simplest version would be:

```
await ExecuteAsync(obj.MethodAsync);
```