# An async method with await vs A normal method that returns a Task

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

In the following program:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static async Task f()
    {
        void action()
        {    
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            Console.WriteLine("4");
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
        await Task.Run(action);
    }
    static async void g()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        Console.WriteLine("1");
        Console.WriteLine("2");
        await f();
        Console.WriteLine("5");
    }
    static void Main()
    {
        g();
        Console.WriteLine("3");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

I can change the function `f` and write it as:

```
static Task f()
{
    void action()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        Console.WriteLine("4");
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
    return Task.Run(action);
}
```

The output doesn't change. Which is preferred? an async `f` with `await` or a normal `f` that returns a `Task`?

**Edit**: The output for both cases:

```
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
```

Comment: `async void g` is a bug. It can't be awaited. Use `async Task` for methods that don't return any results. `await` *awaits* an already active asynchronous operation to complete without blocking the caller. You can't compare `await` with a method returning `Task` because they simply don't do the same things. You use `await` to await the task started by the method that returned the task

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Can you correct the code for me?

Comment: In your example `the output doesn't change` isn't true. If you didn't block the main thread with `ReadKey` the application would terminate without waiting for the other methods to complete, or even start. You have to use `async Task Main()` and `await g();` to ensure the application works correctly

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38017016/async-task-then-await-task-vs-task-then-return-task

Comment: Alsways worth the read: [Eliding Async and Await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html) - StevenC's blog

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I tested: in both cases removing `Readkey` has the same result.

Comment: `async void` methods are intended for async event handlers of GUI applications (WinForms/WPF). In general should be avoided. You can learn more about `async void` methods [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void "Avoid async void").

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Nice question. Let me explain you,
In case you have used `async void` and the method throws some Exception as this process is done without `awaiting` the system will fail to handle the exception and the process terminates the application.

It is always advisable to use `async Task` or `async Task<bool> or async Task<int>` just await the method while calling to check every happened well or not.

It is bad practice to us `async void`

Comment: Do you mean exception handling is different in the two cases?

Comment: You cannot handle exception if thrown from async void methods. Try throwing new Exception from async void method and see what happens, use a try catch in the calling method

Comment: My test shows that if an exception is thrown in `f` the result is the same in both cases.

Comment: `f` is of type `async void` or `async Task` ?

Comment: You can see the complete program in the question. Including the definition of `f` .

Comment: can you attach the console output after throwing exception

Comment: `static  Task f()
    {
        void action()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("4");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
        throw new Exception();
        return Task.Run(action);
    }`

Comment: with a try block in g(), the output is the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227601/discussion-between-krishna-chaitanya-and-minimus-heximus).