# Correct usage for Nito.AsyncEx.AsyncContext.Run

Tags: c#, nito.asyncex

I am using the excellent library from [Steven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary) called [AsyncEx](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.AsyncEx/) to help me baby-step the transition of an old codebases across to the async world.

The docs say to use a delegate:

```
class Program
{
  static async Task<int> AsyncMain()
  {
    ..
  }

  static int Main(string[] args)
  {
    return AsyncContext.Run(AsyncMain);
  }
}
```

When calling a method with a lambda expression, should I be doing:

```
var blah = AsyncContext.Run(() => MyMethodAsync(myvar));
```

or specify the async/wait in the call?

```
var blah = AsyncContext.Run( async () => await MyMethodAsync(myvar));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I now believe that this is the same as [Return Task or Await Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38017016/async-task-then-await-task-vs-task-then-return-task) and therefore [Rene's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5528593/ren%c3%a9-vogt) answer there will be correct

poorly summarized here as -- bit more overhead in await for the compiler, but basically the same at runtime.

Comment: Correct. I have a [blog post on the subject](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html), but the conclusion is it doesn't really matter in this case.