# ASP.NET Core Endpoint of type Task<T> returns fine without any await...how?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Updated below...

So this is a random question that came about from a discussion over what I consider the over usage of await in projects at work...

Not sure why I never tried it until now, other than the fact that it's weird and random, but the fact it does work just makes me wonder...how?

The .Result usage was only used to get the responseMessage. I know that is blocking and no bueno and it is for demo purposes only...

So this endpoint works fine...nothing is awaited

```cs
[HttpGet("kitteh")]
public Task<string> GetCatFact()
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var res = client.GetAsync("https://catfact.ninja/fact").Result;
    return res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

There's obviously something in the default ASP.NET pipleline that ultimately unwraps the task in order to return the result...but where...or how?

Is this "less efficient" than awaiting in the endpoint itself as the magic taking place behind the scenes is ultimately just blocking to get the result of the returned task?

**Updated**

So, I am still skeptical and don't think the answer is as easy as "yes it is blocking" or "not it is not blocking" unless there's some legit proof or something to indicate one way or the other. I tried digging through the code myself, and I still don't have a solid answer but...I do know more than I did before...

I simplified the endpoints I have been testing this with...

```
        [HttpGet("taskstring")]
        public Task<string> TaskString()
        {
            return Task.FromResult("Where does this block?");
        }
        
        [HttpGet("asyncstring")]
        public async Task<string> AsyncString()
        {
            return await Task.FromResult("This definitely doesn't block");
        }
```

I stepped through a bunch of code and ultimately landed on ObjectMethodExecutor and AwaitableObjectResultExecutor which sparked some interest.

What appears to happen for both the endpoint versions above is the same or nearly the same, at least the execution of these two endpoints and the code covered below. There's a boatload that goes on during this and even though the rider debugger is great, it's not possible to see a lot of the values while debugging due to "Evaluation is not allowed: The thread is not at a GC-safe point".

When the endpoint is called but prior to the endpoint beginning execution...
ObjectMethodExecutor.ctor is called

- This does a lot of inspection of the endpoint to determine a bunch of things
- One of the checks is to is determine if the method is "async" and it ultimately calls AwaitableInfo.IsTypeAwaitable to check for the required methods/properties and interfaces to ensure it is
- If it is, which in the case of returning Task of string it is, makes sense given the above info

  - ObjectMethodExecutor.GetExecutorAsync() is called
  - AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute is then called

    - this type inherits ActionMethodExecutor which overrides the Execute method
    - executor.ExecuteAsync(executor type of ObjectMethodExecutorAwaitable) is then called, and awaited

      - this returns a result of type object, boxing yeah I know
    - The endpoint then actually executes and returns to AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute
    - the result is then passed to ConvertToActionResult along with the return type, the T of Task of T and the mapper implementation
    - the mapped ActionResult is then returned

So...I'm still not certain 100% either way but there is a lot of effort put into inspecting the endpoint that is being called and determining if it's async or not, which would make it seem logical to think this is an attempt to avoid something...maybe blocking?

So...does it block...maybe? Seeing that there is an await from the indirect caller of the endpoint, I'd lean towards, no...but it seems really difficult to say still.

What I do now know is...

- It definitely does await the endpoint call, albeit indirectly
- It converts the Task of string return type to an IActionResult
- An async and task only version seem to follow the exact some flow shown above
- A non async version does not

So, based on all of that...@Phil's answer seems to be pretty spot on with what I found...

"The framework supports asynchronous controller actions. In order to do so, it would need to inspect the return value of your methods. If the method returns a Task, it will ultimately await on the result before responding.

Even if your action itself does all the awaiting, it still has to return a Task so the caller will still wait (the alternative being some ugly blocking code)."

[image]

Thanks to all for participating in an extremely random question that doesn't hold much value to truly understand

Comment: I guess some insight into where and if it is in fact "less efficient" as it may potentially be blocking where awaiting it in the controller wouldn't?

Comment: @Phil I am aware of that. I am asking if not awating in this endpoint would utlimately lead to the default pipeline blocking to get the result as opposed to using await in the endpoint itself

Comment: You're dealing with HTTP so there's always something waiting for the response. I don't think it would matter where that wait comes from in this instance (in the controller or in the thing that calls the controller)

Comment: Also, there are some differences `return Task` as opposed to `return await Task`. See [this excellent post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38017016/283366) and the [linked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19098143/283366)

Comment: @Phil yeah, thanks. What initially sparked this all was me pointing out the over usage of await at work and I showed the drastic difference in lowered code from a method that uses await vs the same one that doesn't. Some of them seem to think it's better to use await almost everywhere instead of only awaiting where "necessary". I guess "necessary" can be a bit hard to define. But I also think they're just misunderstanding "async all the way"

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption here is basically correct...

> There's obviously something in the default ASP.NET pipleline that ultimately unwraps the task in order to return the result

The framework supports [asynchronous controller actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/actions?view=aspnetcore-6.0#defining-actions). In order to do so, it would need to inspect the return value of your methods. If the method returns a `Task`, it will ultimately *await* on the result before responding.

Even if your action itself does all the *awaiting*, it still has to return a `Task` so the caller will still wait (the alternative being some ugly blocking code).

As has been pointed out in [some other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38017016/283366), there are some performance improvements to be had by not awaiting a returned `Task` so I would write your action as

```cs
public async Task<string> GetCatFact()
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var res = await client.GetAsync("https://catfact.ninja/fact");
    return res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); // no await
}
```

Your controller handles waiting for the remote response but delegates waiting for the content stream to the caller.

Comment: You're the man @Phil

Comment: After debugging the code in rider, I believe what you said appears to be correct. Added some updates if you're interested and I really appreciate you taking to the time.

Answer (score 1):

> There's obviously something in the default ASP.NET pipleline that ultimately unwraps the task in order to return the result...but where...or how?

ASP.NET *asynchronously* waits for your task to complete, and then it sends the HTTP response based on the result of the task. It's logically similar to `await`: an asynchronous wait.

> Is this "less efficient" than awaiting in the endpoint itself as the magic taking place behind the scenes is ultimately just blocking to get the result of the returned task?

Yes. It is less efficient to block.

ASP.NET doesn't block; it asynchronously waits. Blocking ties up a thread. So when the code calls `.Result`, it will be using a thread just to wait for that `HttpClient` call to complete.

The proper solution is to keep `async` and `await`:

```
[HttpGet("kitteh")]
public async Task<string> GetCatFact()
{
  var client = new HttpClient();
  var res = await client.GetAsync("https://catfact.ninja/fact");
  return await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

This way, while the `GetAsync` is in progress, the thread is yielded back to the ASP.NET runtime and is available for handling other requests, instead of being blocked waiting for the `GetAsync` to complete.

More information: `Task<string>` is part of the method signature. ASP.NET has special understanding of the `Task<T>` type and knows to asynchronously wait for it. `async` is *not* part of the method signature. ASP.NET knows whether your method returns `Task`, but it has no idea whether it's `async` (and doesn't care). [So, in some situations, it's OK to elide the keywords](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html) (as described on my blog, but only when the method implementation is trivial. If there's *any* logic in the method, keep the `async` and `await`.

Comment: I appreciate the detailed response, and I assumed it was blocking but was not sure. I understand what the "proper solution" is but that becomes a bit more complex when adding other classes with their own awaits. I lean towards omitting async/await usage as much as possible, because I think constantly using it eliminates the need to understand it, but also understand there's risk involved. So if, hypothetically, this API call was in a separate service that was already awaited...then what? Two awaits when not necessary? But why? Scalability blah blah blah?

Comment: Also, one last dumb question...how do you know it's actually blocking? I stepped through so much code in hopes to find something but could not.

Comment: `Two awaits when not necessary? But why? Scalability blah blah blah?` It's more about getting the code to compile. ;)  It's not possible to remove the second `await` because the return type for an `async Task<string>` method must be `string`, not `Task<string>`.

Comment: `how do you know it's actually blocking?` It's the only possible behavior. Basic HTTP has only one response per request, and that response *can't* be sent until ASP.NET knows what the response *is* (i.e., the task has completed).

Comment: @StephenCleary what's your opinion on `return Task` vs `return await Task` (the difference between the code in my answer and the code in yours)?

Comment: @StephenCleary you misunderstood the question and assumed I don't even know the basics, which I really appreciate, but what I am actually asking is...if you have a separate service that awaits this API call then why would the endpoint that calls that service also need to await it> Again, two awaits? It can't possibly be necessary and you yourself in your article say it's acceptable to elide await in scenarios where it's a passthrough. Which is honestly what started all of this because the company I recently joined seems to have mistaken "async all the way" for "await all the way"

Comment: @SomeTonyGuy: If you're talking about two different processes (e.g., client and server), then `async` on the client is completely different than `async` on the server. In modern code, both are likely to be `async`, but over the network it's just HTTP. Put another way, each process should itself decide if it should be `async`. If one API is just calling another API, then that is normally done with `async`. It's possible to elide but I would only do so if the implementation is trivial, which is usually not the case.

Comment: After more digging, a lot more, it looks like what @Phil said was correct. The endpoints are inspected and it determines whether the return type is awaitable, AwaitableInfo.IsTypeAwaitable, and dependent upon that it creates an ActionMethodExecutor, and is this case it's actually of type AwaitableObjectResultExecutor. This is what ultimately, indirectly, calls the endpoint and that call is awaited. ActionMethodExecutor is an abstract class and there's various other implementations for different scenarios. Thanks all for helping me answer a pretty useless question.