# Difference between those two methods returning Task

Tags: c#, async-await

What's the Semantic difference between those two methods?

```
    public Task DoSomething()
    {
        return Task.Run(() => MyFunction());
    }

    public async Task DoSomethingAsync()
    {
        await Task.Run(() => MyFunction());
    }
```

Is there something I should think to choose between one or the other?

Comment: Is this a library/framework or an application built on a specific framework

Comment: There's big a difference in exception propagation and synchronization context handling, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21033150/1768303).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The actual difference is this:

1. The first method will call `Task.Run` and return the resulting task
2. The second method will be transformed into an async state machine that will call `Task.Run`, then queue up a continuation that when this task completes, will continue executing your method

In terms of "which one should I choose", here's the general guideline I use:

> If all your method is going to do in relation to tasks is to return them then **do not use `async/await`**
>   If, instead, you need to "wait for" a task to complete, then do more stuff, then use `async/await`.

I am sure there are exceptions to this but I have yet to find any.

So of those two methods, pick the first.

Comment: so in above example first approach is better in this case?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad, yes it is better... http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/26/keywords/5993/await#t=201607261114381411264