# How to best create multiple tasks for Task.WhenAll()?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library

What's best practice when creating multiple tasks for `Task.WhenAll()`?

Is there a difference between these two async-await alternatives below in terms of performance, and/or behavior under an exception?

They both work, but is there any difference?

*Alternative 1:*

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   // call DoWork() to prepare data
   await Task.WhenAll(myObjects.Select(o => Task.Run(() => o.DoWork()));

  // update ui ...
}
```

*Alternative 2:*

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   // call DoWork () to prepare data - note the async-await around the return Task
   await Task.WhenAll(myObjects.Select(async o => await Task.Run(() => o.DoWork()));

   // update ui...
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: What work is done in `DoWork`, why do you need `Task.Run`? Method 2 introduces an extra state machine. 1 is better. If you are not doing anything after an await statement then just return the task.

Comment: See ["Any difference between “await Task.Run(); return;” and “return Task.Run()”?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21033150/1768303).