# Do we need to include async / await syntax when trying to create a List of Tasks in .NET?

Tags: .net, async-await

Given the following code:

```
var tasks1 = users.Select(async user => await Task.Delay(1000));
await Task.WhenAll(tasks1);
```

do I need to include the `async` / `await` syntax in this line of code?

I thought I can also write it like ...

```
var tasks2 = users.Select(user => Task.Delay(1000));
await Task.WhenAll(tasks2);
```

which [does compile and run](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eY66co).

Is this something to do with error handling?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any difference between “await Task.Run(); return;” and “return Task.Run()”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21033150/11683)

Answer (score 1):

When you don't need a `await` , you could directly return the task (and skip marking the method as `async`)

There are some differences with the stacktrace when an exception is thrown.

Also small difference, when using dispose (or `using`), you probably need a `await`. Otherwise stuff could get disposed too soon.

> do I need to include the async / await syntax in this line of code?

So probably not in this case :)