# Async Method Call Non-Async Method Best Practices

Tags: c#, async-await

For some reason I need to inherit a class to implement an Async method which is the below implementation that it is best practices

1.

```
protected override Task<TResult> OnExecuteAsync<TResult><TResult>()
{
        return Task.Run<TResult>(() => DoSomething());
}
```

2. 

```
protected override async Task<TResult> OnExecuteAsync<TResult><TResult>()
{
        return await Task.Run<TResult>(() => DoSomething());
}
```

I want to know which one is the best implementation?

Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21033150/any-difference-between-await-task-run-return-and-return-task-run

Comment: Do 1., not 2.  It doesn't not add anything to await a task you just ran.

Comment: Take a look at this: [Eliding Async and Await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html). Quoting from the article: *"Do not elide by default. 1. Use the async and await for natural, easy-to-read code. 2. Do consider eliding when the method is just a passthrough or overload."*

Answer (score 3):

In short, if the base *class* or *interface* is expecting a `Task` result and you have synchronous method and it doesn't need to run in a task, all you need to do is give it a *pre-completed task*.

The simplest thing to do, would be just leave the `async` *keyword*, return the result, and ignore (or `pragma` out) the warning. You **do not** need to *spin-up* a new *task* via `Task.Run` (this would be an inefficient way of achieving nothing). In this case the compiler automatically takes care of everything for you (albeit with a warning that you have nothing to await)

```
protected override async Task<TResult> OnExecuteAsync<TResult>()
{
    return DoSomething();
}
```

You could also use [`Task.FromResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.fromresult?view=netcore-3.1) to create the *pre-completed task*. The only caveat is if the *consumer* is calling `await`, in which case you should be nice and make sure any *exceptions* are returned on the resulting `Task` with [`Task.FromException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.fromexception?view=netcore-3.1). This is analogous to what the *compiler generated* `IAsyncStateMachine` implementation (*async and await pattern*) would automatically do.

```
protected override Task<TResult> OnExecuteAsync<TResult>()
{
    try
    {
        return Task.FromResult(DoSomething());
    }
    catch(exception ex)
    { 
        // place any exception on the returned task
        return Task.FromException<TResult>(ex);
    }
}
```