# Await.Task<>.Run freezing after finish

Tags: c#, async-await

I am running an `await Task< >.Run(() =>` inside an `async` method.
The code in the await runs to competition but never returns.
The next line after the await never gets called.
Anyone have any input?

How async method is called

```cs
var task1 = ConvertToMagickImageAsync(tpFileInfo, fileInfo, density, inputModel.Quality);

task1.Wait();
```

Async method

```cs
protected virtual async Task<IXPubMagickImageOutputModel> ConvertToMagickImageAsync(
   Tuple<string, string, string> tpFileInfo
    , Tuple<IXPubMagickFileModel, IXPubMagickFileModel, IXPubMagickFileModel> fileInfo
    , Tuple<double, double, double> density
    , int quality
    )
{
    string error;
    var outputModel = new XPubMagickImageOutputModel
    {
        ResultContent = new SortedDictionary<int, IXPubMagickImageNameModel>()
    };

    MagickFormat extension = fileInfo.Item3.FileExtension switch
    {
        "png" => MagickFormat.Png,
        "jpg" => MagickFormat.Jpg,
        "jpeg" => MagickFormat.Jpeg,
        "bmp" => MagickFormat.Bmp,
        _ => MagickFormat.Jpg,
    };

    var magickSettings = new MagickReadSettings();
    if (density.Item1 > 0)
        magickSettings.Density = new Density(density.Item1);
    else
        magickSettings.Density = new Density(density.Item2, density.Item3);
  var ret= await Task< IXPubMagickImageOutputModel>.Run(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            using (var images = new MagickImageCollection())
            {
                var page = 0;
                images.Read(tpFileInfo.Item1, magickSettings);
                ////if (images.Count > 0 && images[0].Format == MagickFormat.Pdf)
                if (images.Count > 0)
                {
                    var sb = new StringBuilder(tpFileInfo.Item2);
                    sb.Append(@"\").Append(fileInfo.Item1.FileName);

                    var sb1 = new StringBuilder(tpFileInfo.Item3);
                    sb1.Append(".").Append(extension.ToString().ToLower());

                    foreach (var image in images)
                    {
                        image.Quality = quality;
                        image.Format = extension;
                        outputModel.ResultContent[page] = new XPubMagickImageNameModel
                        {
                            MagickImage = new MagickImage(image),
                            ImageName = $"{sb}_{page}_{sb1}"
                        };
                        page++;

                        //outputModels.Add(outputModel);
                    }// end foreach (var image in images)
                }  // end if (images.Count > 0 && images[0].Format == MagickFormat.Pdf)
            }

            error = String.Empty;
            outputModel.Result = XPubMagickOperationResultEnum.Success;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            error = $"Exception: {ex.Message}";
            outputModel.Result = XPubMagickOperationResultEnum.ErrorMagickReadFailure;
        }
        return outputModel;
    });
    int a = 1;
    //}  // end using (var images = new MagickImageCollection())
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: this question needs code formating

Comment: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to await in the method.
Just return the task and await outside in the Task.Wait()

```
 var task1 = ConvertToMagickImageAsync(tpFileInfo, fileInfo, density, inputModel.Quality);
    
    
task1.Wait();
```

And method won't be async anymore

```
protected virtual Task<IXPubMagickImageOutputModel> ConvertToMagickImageAsync(
   Tuple<string, string, string> tpFileInfo
    , Tuple<IXPubMagickFileModel, IXPubMagickFileModel, IXPubMagickFileModel> fileInfo
    , Tuple<double, double, double> density, int quality)
{
    string error;
    var outputModel = new XPubMagickImageOutputModel
    {
        ResultContent = new SortedDictionary<int, IXPubMagickImageNameModel>()
    };

    MagickFormat extension = fileInfo.Item3.FileExtension switch
    {
        "png" => MagickFormat.Png,
        "jpg" => MagickFormat.Jpg,
        "jpeg" => MagickFormat.Jpeg,
        "bmp" => MagickFormat.Bmp,
        _ => MagickFormat.Jpg,
    };

    var magickSettings = new MagickReadSettings();
    if (density.Item1 > 0)
        magickSettings.Density = new Density(density.Item1);
    else
        magickSettings.Density = new Density(density.Item2, density.Item3);
  return Task<IXPubMagickImageOutputModel>.Run(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            using (var images = new MagickImageCollection())
            {
                var page = 0;
                images.Read(tpFileInfo.Item1, magickSettings);
                ////if (images.Count > 0 && images[0].Format == MagickFormat.Pdf)
                if (images.Count > 0)
                {
                    var sb = new StringBuilder(tpFileInfo.Item2);
                    sb.Append(@"\").Append(fileInfo.Item1.FileName);

                    var sb1 = new StringBuilder(tpFileInfo.Item3);
                    sb1.Append(".").Append(extension.ToString().ToLower());

                    foreach (var image in images)
                    {
                        image.Quality = quality;
                        image.Format = extension;
                        outputModel.ResultContent[page] = new XPubMagickImageNameModel
                        {
                            MagickImage = new MagickImage(image),
                            ImageName = $"{sb}_{page}_{sb1}"
                        };
                        page++;

                        //outputModels.Add(outputModel);
                    }// end foreach (var image in images)
                }  // end if (images.Count > 0 && images[0].Format == MagickFormat.Pdf)
            }

            error = String.Empty;
            outputModel.Result = XPubMagickOperationResultEnum.Success;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            error = $"Exception: {ex.Message}";
            outputModel.Result = XPubMagickOperationResultEnum.ErrorMagickReadFailure;
        }
        return outputModel;
    });
}
```

Comment: This [changes observable behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21033150/11683), which may not be desired. It is also a mere hack if only used to avoid the deadlock (there are proper ways to avoid it).

Comment: The accepted answer in the question above says "the async/await version is more prone to dead-locking on a non-default synchronization context." And advises of "Change it to a non-async version and it won't dead-lock"