Why would I use async/await with Task.Run?
Is there a difference in this code?
public void Main()
{
  Console.Writeline("Foo");
  Task.Run(() => 
  {
    Console.Writeline("Bar");
  });
  Console.Writeline("Baz");
}

Or this?
public void Main()
{
  Console.Writeline("Foo");
  DoSomething();
  Console.Writeline("Baz");
}

public async void DoSomething()
{
   await Task.Run(() => 
   {
     Console.Writeline("Bar");
   });
}

I can't figure out what is gained by using async/await with Task.Run, though CoPilot is telling me I should.
My goal is to find the "right" way to execute "fire and forget" code -- code that needs to run, but that I don't need to wait for.

If you not wait for them at all, then you can never be sure if they failed or stopped at any step or even start running - when the application quits, then all pending and running tasks were shut off. Can you live with that?

BTW Both codes do exactly the same

Strong possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21033150/any-difference-between-await-task-run-return-and-return-task-run

These kind of hypotheticals are hard to comment on since neither approach makes any sense with the code as written. Replace Console.WriteLine with some meaningful code, and then we can give useful advice.

Btw Console apps typically make for poor demonstrations of async await because they don't obviously do anything else while awaiting the result, btw, so the notion of "while we are waiting for the massive DB query to run, we can still click other buttons in the Ui/see the progress bar update" etc

You run a task to produce a result.  Maybe you're uninterested what that looks like, say a dbase update, but it is still quite important that you know that the result was in fact produced.  An exception is a result as well.  Code that silently fails is extremely hard to troubleshoot and maintain.

You guys want a good laugh? Here is a subsequent question that is a direct manifestation/example of what you've explained to me here... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79248199/does-executioncontext-always-flow-into-a-task-run-or-a-parallel-foreach

Firstly, your two code blocks are functionally identical.
In the example you have given, as you don't await DoSomething() then you can't (easily) know if it succeeded, completed, faulted or for that matter even began.
If you are happy with this constraint then it's absolutely fine to have what's known as a Fire and Forget task.
Calling await will provide you with fault information.
Take the following example:
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Foo");
            var dt = DoSomething();  // Fire and forget
            Console.WriteLine("Baz");
            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch{
            Console.WriteLine("A fault occured");
        }

    }

    static async Task DoSomething()
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            throw new Exception("My error");
        });
    }

The exception raised by DoSomething() will not be captured.
As opposed to:
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Foo");
            var dt = DoSomething();
            Console.WriteLine("Baz");
            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit");
            Console.ReadLine();
            await dt; // Check if the Task has finished
        }
        catch{
            Console.WriteLine("A fault occured");
        }

    }

    static async Task DoSomething()
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            throw new Exception("My error");
        });
    }

Which will capture the exception at await dt; and allow you to take the necessary action.
As for your long running Task question.  You can Fire and Forget, but you can't really ever Forget.
Here's an example you can try:
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            using CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var task1 = FireAndForget(cts.Token);

            Console.WriteLine("Fire forget Task is running....press ENTER to exit");
            Console.ReadLine();

            // Uncomment these two lines
            // cts.Cancel();
            // await task1;

        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            // If the above are uncommented then the task terminated
            Console.WriteLine("Task was cancelled");
        }
        catch (Exception) { throw; }

        // If the above lines are still commented, the task will terminate here
        // when the main process terminates
    }

    static async Task FireAndForget(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (true) // Background long running task
            {
                ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            }
        }, CancellationToken.None);
    }


Your first approach, with an ignored Task.Run, is called fire-and-forget. Any exception will be stored inside the task, but it will never be surfaced because you don't .Wait() or await the task.
Your second approach, with an async void method, is called fire-and-crash. Any exception will be rethrown on the SynchronizationContext or TaskScheduler that was captured when the async void method started, which in this case is the ThreadPoolTaskScheduler. So the exception will be rethrown by a ThreadPool thread, causing the process to crash after raising the AppDomain.UnhandledException event.
