# Return Task or await and ConfigureAwait(false)

Tags: c#, async-await

Suppose to have a service library with a method like this

```
public async Task<Person> GetPersonAsync(Guid id) {
  return await GetFromDbAsync<Person>(id);
}
```

Following the best practices for the *SynchronizationContext* is better to use

```
public async Task<Person> GetPersonAsync(Guid id) {
  return await GetFromDbAsync<Person>(id).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

But when you have only one operation (I think) is better to return the Task directly. See [At the end of an async method, should I return or await?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886992/at-the-end-of-an-async-method-should-i-return-or-await)

```
public Task<Person> GetPersonAsync(Guid id) {
  return GetFromDbAsync<Person>(id);
}
```

In this last case you can't use *ConfigureAwait(false)* because the method is not awaited.

What is the best solution (and why)?

Comment: I think the last one (delegation) is the clearest and does not involve creation of additional state machine. Unless you're doing *something else* inside the method that's dependent on async call result, I see no point in using `await`.

Comment: The last one makes the most sense to me. It returns a Task which you can await from wherever you're calling GetPersonAsync

Comment: So the solution that return the Task directly doesn't capture the SynchronizationContext?

Comment: What you're doing is allowing your caller to decide how *they* want to wait for that `Task` to complete - if *that* code is `async`, *it* can decide whether to capture context when `await`ing the result.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever ok, thus in the latest example there's not the switching context overhead?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Each option has its own specifics, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21033150/1768303) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22672984/1768303). If you understand them, you could decide what's the best one for you.

> So the solution that return the Task directly doesn't capture the
>   SynchronizationContext?

It's not the task that captures the current synchronization context. It's [`TaskAwaiter.OnCompleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.taskawaiter.oncompleted(v=vs.110).aspx) (or `ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.OnCompleted`, in case of `ConfigureAwait`), which is indirectly invoked by the code generated by C# compiler as a part of the `await` statement for the task.

So, if you don't use `await`, you shouldn't be worried about `SynchronizationContext` capturing, it doesn't magically happen on its own. This probably makes the 3rd option the most favorable one, but keep in mind its [exception propagation behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21082631/1768303).

Comment: thanks. I think this is a very domain specific choice. Do any difference if the method called is really async? For example an async query with EF (the error handling is important).

Comment: Another good reading is: [Async Performance: Understanding the Costs of Async and Await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456402.aspx)

Comment: @sevenmy, An `async Task` method would never throws until you observe the task with `await task`, `task.Wait()`, or `task.Result`. OTOH, a non-async `Task` method may throw immediately. **However**, in your client code, you should make no assumptions. Always code like it can throw either synchronously (on the same stack frame) or asynchronously.