# Wrapping Task<T> but not awaiting it in the wrapper

Tags: c#

Say you wrap the entity framework `DbContext` `SaveChangesAsync()`. So the original method returns `Task<int>`.

So when wrapped, is there any difference between:

```
public Task<int> SaveChangesAsync()
{
    return dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

and

```
public async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync()
{
    return await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Comment: There is a slight difference in that with `Task.Run` you could have unhandled exceptions, but with this code, it will be awaited at some point. So I don't think I could accept that as a duplicate

Comment: See the edit on the question and the code in the answers, the `Task.Run` is irrelevant

Comment: @Lukazoid sorry I still can't see the duplication

Comment: In both cases, the question is "is there a difference between returning a `Task` directly and returning the `await`ed `Task`?". Still, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23536848/return-task-or-await-and-configureawaitfalse?rq=1 seems like a better fit for a duplicate.

Comment: I would agree with you @Luaan that is far closer.

Comment: Didn't realise I had originally flagged the possible duplicate as a possible duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098143/what-is-the-purpose-of-return-await-in-c which may be another better option. Hopefully one of these many possible duplicates may answer your question :)