# Is this the correct usage of async/await in MVC with service/repository layer?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, async-await

Using VS2013, EF6.1.1, MVC5, .net 4.5.

I have just started looking into async/await for the first time and I am not sure if this is doing it properly. It appears to work, but could it be simpler? I seem to be sticking async/await in a lot of places for one method call down multiple layers.

All code has been simplified for brevity.

In my MVC controller action method I have:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> TestAction1()
{
    var testResponse = await _testService.TestMethod1(1);

    if (testResponse != null)
    {
        _unitOfWork.CommitAsync();
        return View(testResponse);
    }

    return RedirectToAction("TestAction2");
}
```

My service class is as follows:

```
public class TestService : ITestService
{
    public async Task<TestObject> TestMethod1()
    {
        var testObject1 = await privateMethod1Async();
        if (testObject1 != null) return testObject1;

        testObject1 = await privateMethod2Async();

        return testObject1;
    }

    private async Task<TestObject> privateMethod1Async()
    {
        return await _testRepository.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }

    private async Task<TestObject> privateMethod2Async()
    {
        return await _testRepository.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }
}
```

And my repository method:

```
public async Task<TEntity> FirstOrDefaultAsync()
{
    return await _entitySet.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

Basically, I have a controller method, that calls a service method. The service method is to call the database layer twice, in an async fashion. But I feel that I am changing every single method and layer to deal with async and I wasn't sure if what I have here is correct.

Secondly, in the controller method I am unsure how to call the unit of work commit method asynchronously. The line that has "_unitOfWork.CommitAsync();". I cannot stick an "await" before it as it is a void method.

Any thoughts?

---

EDIT 1

Here is the full version of the repository method call to EF:

```
public async Task<TEntity> FirstOrDefaultAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> 
                                               predicate, params 
                                               Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[]
                                               includeProperties)
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> query = EntitySet;
    if (includeProperties != null && includeProperties.Any())
    {
        query = IncludeProperties(query, includeProperties);
    }
    return await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync(predicate);
}
```

Comment: *The line that has "_unitOfWork.CommitAsync();". I cannot stick an "await" before it as it is a void method.* `public async Task CommitAsync() { ... }`.

Comment: Ah ok, I suppose I can just do nothing with the return of that. So there's no way to use await with a void that I'm missing?

Comment: *I suppose I can just do nothing with the return of that.* No, you can `await` it.

Comment: ok thanks. What about the rest of it? I seem to be adding the same async/await stuff to every methodf and layer, is that right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I see a reoccurring pattern in your code:

```
private async Task<TestObject> privateMethod2Async()
{
    return await _testRepository.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

When you have a single-liner which simply queries your DB for a `Task<T>`, you can avoid the state-machine allocation which `await` causes, and simply return the hot task to the caller (as he'll probably await on it anyway higher up the call-chain):

```
private Task<TestObject> privateMethod2Async()
{
    return _testRepository.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

Note that `async-await` will make you go *"async all the way"*, that's the nature of async. Make sure that you group tasks that can run concurrently using `Task.WhenAll` if possible, for example (not sure this might be the best example):

```
public async Task<TestObject> TestMethod1()
{
    var testObject1 = await privateMethod1Async();
    if (testObject1 != null) return testObject1;

    testObject1 = await privateMethod2Async();

    return testObject1;
}
```

Might be able to turn into:

```
return Task.WhenAny(privateMethod1Async(), privateMethod2Async());
```

given that one of the methods is applicable as a return type.

**Edit:**

> What is the general rule rule of thumb for adding the async/await? is
>   it for a method that does other processing in it? Which, as you point
>   out, this method doesn't?

You would want to use `await` when you'd want to be doing more processing on the returned `Task`. If all you want is to return the actual `Task`, there is no need to await it, you can simply return the hot task. That's the general rule i use. Also note that exception handling is different when you use `return await` vs simply `return`.

You can read more on that in [At the end of an async method, should I return or await?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886992/at-the-end-of-an-async-method-should-i-return-or-await) and [Any difference between "await Task.Run(); return;" and "return Task.Run()"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21033150/any-difference-between-await-task-run-return-and-return-task-run)

Comment: Is `async` necessary in your last example?

Comment: My code was simplified to make it easier to read. However, you do hit a point. What is the generule rule of thumb for adding the sync/await? is it for a method that does other processing in it? Which, as you point out, this method doesn't?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I have updated my question with an edit at the bottom to show the full version of that method. Would you still say it doesnt need the await-async? Also, those 2 method calls need to be done one after the other. One only runs if the first is null.

Comment: @eyeballpaul Regarding the second part, that's why i said it might not be the best example, but i just wanted to convey the point of what could be done. Regarding your edit, yes, you could definitely `return query.FirstOrDefaultAsync(predicate);` and remove the `async` modifier.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have simplified the lower levels to only return "Task", and leave the async-await to the service levels that do more actual work.

Answer (score 3):

`async-await` does have a tendency to crawl upwards in your code base and it's perfectly fine. You should let it rise up as long as it's possible (in a UI event handler it's possible to rise all the way to the top because of the combination of `async-void` and the UI `SynchronizationContext`)

When it isn't possible anymore (the root of a console application for example) you can simply `Wait` the returned task:

```
var task = RunAsync();
task.Wait();
```

Or even better, you can use [Stephen Cleary's `AsyncContext`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncContext):

```
AsyncContext.Run(RunAsync);
```

Comment: Having it all the way down in DB layer, is that the correct way? Considering that will be the hold up?

Comment: @eyeballpaul yes. Otherwise it wouldn't really be asynchronous.

Comment: ok thanks. I have accepted the other answer as it pointed out a few things, one thing being that I didnt need async-await in the lower levels, only returning a task.

Comment: @eyeballpaul that's true... but insignificant.