# Should I add the async modifier if I return a Task in an expensive method?

Tags: c#, async-await

The C# compiler already warns us if we have a method that has the `async` modifier but does not use the `await` operator.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41626221/159145) answer there's no point adding an `await` to the end of an async method (and in that case, just remove the `async` modifier).

But what if the method has an expensive synchronous operation it needs to perform before calling a subsequent true async method?

For example, if I'm using `HttpClient`:

```
private readonly HttpClient client = ...

public Task<HttpResponseMessage> CallMyWebServiceMethod() {

    HttpRequestMessage request = this.SomeExpensiveButSynchronousMethod();

    return this.client.SendAsync( request );
}
```

This code would block the caller (due to `SomeExpensiveButSynchronousMethod`).

However, if I change the code to this:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> CallMyWebServiceMethod() {

    HttpRequestMessage request = this.SomeExpensiveButSynchronousMethod();

    return await this.client.SendAsync( request );
}
```

and I call it like so:

```
HttpResponse response = await myWrapper.CallMyWebServiceMethod();
```

...I understand the TPL would spin up a background thread immediately and then run `CallMyWebServiceMethod` in the background thread, resuming whatever the parent code wants, making the entire call non-blocking in the process, before resuming after the Task completes and returns the `HttpResponse`.

...if that's the case then it seems contradictory.

If I'm wrong, and the call *is* blocking until it gets to `SendAsync` then how can I execute `SomeExpensiveButSynchronousMethod` on the same background thread as the `HttpClient` uses for its request?

Comment: This is really more implementation specific. Do you want the request to be asynchronous or synchronous(blocking)?

Comment: @Tdorno I want to wrap `HttpClient` with my own operations in a way that "preserves" async-ness - assuming that's what we're supposed to do.

Answer (score 3):

> According to this answer there's no point adding an await to the end of an async method (and in that case, just remove the async modifier).

That's an oversimplification. See my blog post on [eliding async and await](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html).

> But what if the method has an expensive synchronous operation it needs to perform before calling a subsequent true async method?

This is a rare case, but the appropriate solution IMO is to [execute the synchronous operation synchronously (i.e., not wrapped in a `Task.Run`) and be sure to document its behavior](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-even-in.html).

> I understand the TPL would spin up a background thread immediately and then run CallMyWebServiceMethod in the background thread, resuming whatever the parent code wants, making the entire call non-blocking in the process, before resuming after the Task completes and returns the HttpResponse.

That is not at all what happens. You may find my [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) helpful. Quote:

> The beginning of an async method is executed just like any other method. That is, it runs synchronously until it hits an “await” (or throws an exception).

In actuality, **both** of your examples synchronously block the caller while executing `SomeExpensiveButSynchronousMethod`.

> If I'm wrong, and the call is blocking until it gets to SendAsync then how can I execute SomeExpensiveButSynchronousMethod on the same background thread as the HttpClient uses for its request?

`HttpClient` doesn't use a background thread for its request, so this part of the question doesn't make sense. For more information on how asynchronous I/O works, see my blog post [There Is No Thread](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html).

To answer the actual question:

> Should I add the async modifier if I return a Task in an expensive method?

Yes. But the *reason* you should do so is not to "make it asynchronous"; it's so that any exceptions from `SomeExpensiveButSynchronousMethod` are captured and placed on the returned `Task`, which is the expected semantic for methods that follow the Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP).

Answer (score 1):

> I understand the TPL would spin up a background thread immediately and then run `CallMyWebServiceMethod`

No, that's not what happens. The first synchronous part of an `async` method executes synchronously. If you want make sure it does not block the current thread, you should use `Task.Run()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your expensive method is going to block the caller either way. `async` doesn't magically create threads for you, that's what `Task` does (sometimes).  So, if you add `async` and await the `SendAsync`, you're just adding state-machine overhead needlessly.

see also http://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html