# What is the correct way to call Polly ExecuteAsync method?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, polly

Executing a Policy, I've see some people call ExecuteAsync like this:

```
...
.ExecuteAsync(async (ct) => await GetEmployeeAsync(employeeId, ct), cancellationToken);
```

And like this:

```
...
.ExecuteAsync(ct => GetEmployeeAsync(employeeId, ct), cancellationToken);
```

What is the difference and which one should be used?

Comment: I don't think there is any significant difference in this 2 snippets. Just use one that you like.

Comment: The first generates another `IAsyncStatemachine` which is more *CIL*, and is an inefficient way of achieving no applicable difference

Comment: Related: [At the end of an async method, should I return or await?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886992/at-the-end-of-an-async-method-should-i-return-or-await)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this simple case, there's no semantic difference. The version eliding `async` and `await` has an almost-immeasurable performance benefit.

In the general case, there are some [pitfalls when omiting or leaving out `async` and `await`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html). As a general rule, if the code does anything non-trivial, then you should keep the `async` and `await`.

Only elide(leave-out) the `async`/`await` if the code is truly trivial - like in this case, when the delegate just binds `employeeId` on `GetEmployeeAsync`.