# Do I need to add Async to my Controller Actions in Visual Studio 2017 ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2017

I just converted my Visual Studio 2015 ASP.NET MVC Core project to Visual Studio 2017...and I get the following Informational messages in my Error List

Message IDE1006 Naming rule violation: Missing suffix: 'Async'

This message occurs in my Controllers that focus on the following:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
```

This also applies to Create, Delete, Details and Edit. The messages show as Informational  and applies to over 1,000 occurences in my project. It appears that I need to change Index to IndexAsync
ie.
    Change from:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
public async Task<IActionResult> Create()
public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
```

Change to:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> IndexAsync()
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateAsync()
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteAsync(int? id)
public async Task<IActionResult> DetailsAysnc(int? id)
```

This appears to be optional at this time as my project will Build and it's not an issue in VS 2015. I don't mind doing the work,I need confirmation that changing this in Visual Studio 2017 ASP.NET Core is the correct approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Microsoft is nudging you in the direction of suffixing your your asynchronous methods with the word async.  Why?  The [release notes](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes) for Visual Studio 2017 mention this tidbit.

> Task-like return types for async methods: This introduces the ability
>   to return any task-like type from an async method. Previously these
>   return types were constrained to `Task<T>` and `Task`.

Sounds like it's going to become less obvious which methods are asynchronous just from examining their return types.  Suffixing them with async may be a good idea.  Before VS was making this "suggestion" there was a [previous stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15951774/does-the-use-of-the-async-suffix-in-a-method-name-depend-on-whether-the-async) debating the convention. Stephen Toub from Microsoft addressed it, and I quote.

> If a public method is Task-returning and is asynchronous in nature (as
>   opposed to a method that is known to always execute synchronously to
>   completion but still returns a Task for some reason), it should have
>   an “Async” suffix. That’s the guideline. The primary goal here with
>   the naming is to make it very obvious to a consumer of the
>   functionality that the method being invoked will likely not complete
>   all of its work synchronously; it of course also helps with the case
>   where functionality is exposed with both synchronous and asynchronous
>   methods such that you need a name difference to distinguish them. How
>   the method achieves its asynchronous implementation is immaterial to
>   the naming: whether async/await is used to garner the compiler’s help,
>   or whether types and methods from System.Threading.Tasks are used
>   directly (e.g. TaskCompletionSource) doesn’t really matter, as that
>   doesn’t affect the method’s signature as far as a consumer of the
>   method is concerned.
>
> Of course, there are always exceptions to a guideline. The most
>   notable one in the case of naming would be cases where an entire
>   type’s raison d’etre is to provide async-focused functionality, in
>   which case having Async on every method would be overkill, e.g. the
>   methods on Task itself that produce other Tasks.
>
> As for void-returning asynchronous methods, it’s not desirable to have
>   those in public surface area, since the caller has no good way of
>   knowing when the asynchronous work has completed. If you must expose a
>   void-returning asynchronous method publicly, though, you likely do
>   want to have a name that conveys that asynchronous work is being
>   initiated, and you could use the “Async” suffix here if it made sense.
>   Given how rare this case should be, I’d argue it’s really a
>   case-by-case kind of decision.
>
> I hope that helps, Steve

Bottomline, it's informational.  But as Microsoft has expanded the return types beyond Task, it it beggining to look more and more like best practice.  Use your own judgement.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that for MVC Controller classes, that in addition to adding Async to the method name, I needed to add [ActionName("MethodName")] as a method attribute where "MethodName" did not have Async at the end.  If I didn't add the ActionName attribute, the code would compile, but the URL would not route to the method unless I added Async in the URL as well.  I don't want Async in my URLs so I ended up adding ActionName attributes everywhere.  It seems like the MVC routing engine should try to find the Async methods, but it doesn't.

Comment: Worse than that, by default it will look for views with Async at the end of the view name, unless you specify which view you want.  And they aren't interested in fixing it (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/6046/ide1006-naming-rule-violation-missing-suffix-async.html)