# ASP.NET Core 3.1 areas return 404 on some methods but not on the Index one

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have the following simple solution, with one Area named Test:

[image: The solution]

In my Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(AzureADB2CDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddAzureADB2C(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options));
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "test",
                pattern: "Test/{controller=Map}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
    }
}
```

And in the MapController.cs:

```
[Area("Test")]
[Route("test/[controller]")]
public class MapController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [Route("[action]")]
    public IActionResult LoadNearbySitesAsync()
    {
        return Ok("data");
    }
}
```

When I try to reach https://localhost:44319/Test/Map/Index, the Index page is showing up.
When I try to reach https://localhost:44319/Test/Map/LoadNearbySitesAsync, I get an HTTP 404 exception:

[image]

I also get an HTTP 404 exception when I try accessing the `LoadNearbySitesAsync` method with jQuery `$.get` function.

Before, I was using ASP.NET Core 2.2 and it was working fine. Now that I switched to ASP.NET Core 3.1 and the new Endpoints stuff, I can't get this to work.

I tried different combinations of attributes `[Area]` and `[Route]`, I even added a `[Route("[action]")]` attribute on the `LoadNearbySitesAsync` method, nothing worked so far.

Any idea what I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove `[Route("[action]")]` from `LoadNearbySitesAsync` action and remove `[Route("Test/[controller]")]` from controller
2. Change the `MapControllerRoute` to `MapAreaControllerRoute`

```cs
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
        endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
            "Test",
            "Test",
            "Test/{controller=Map}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");  
});
```

3. change the name of action from `LoadNearbySitesAsync` to
   `LoadNearbySites` or call this url
   `https://localhost:44319/Test/Map/LoadNearbySites`

for more information you can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40695424/7086678)

Comment: I followed your recommendations, but still get the same result (404). Thanks for the link, it's informative!

Comment: @DotNetMatt Glad i help you. but i updated my answer and it works successfully

Comment: Thanks @Farhad!! It worked, I think the key missing element was the call to `endpoints.MapControllers()`.

Comment: @DotNetMatt Good luck :)

Comment: For me, it was adding area attribute [Area("Test")] to the controller, that made mine resolve. Adding the endpoints.MapControllers(); line didn't seem to make a difference.