# ASP.NET Core 3.1 areas return 404

Tags: routes, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1, area

I tried this link  [Stack Link FOR 404 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60896951/asp-net-core-3-1-areas-return-404-on-some-methods-but-not-on-the-index-one)   but error not going showing 404 error for area

```
 public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        services.AddDbContext<BCAContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("BCAContext")));
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

           app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            //endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
            //    "Student",
            //    "Student",
            //    "Student/{controller=StudentExam}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "areas", pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=StudentExam}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

      
        //database
        using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
        {
            var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<BCAContext>();
            context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
            context.Database.EnsureCreated();
            //context.Database.Migrate();
        }
    }
}
```

Two Areas **Student** and  **Admin**  i am using please refer link below

Structure Image

[image]

controller

```
 namespace BCA_New_System.Areas.Student.Controllers
{
  public class StudentExamController : Controller
  {
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
  }
}
```

index page

```
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
Layout = "~/Areas/Student/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
 }

 <h1>Index</h1>
```

Comment: can you just try pattern?                                                      
  endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "areas",
                    pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Dashboard}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

Comment: which should i remove or add this line ?

Comment: remove your student map area controller endpoint and use the above

Comment: sorry the first comment has error can you remove your student mapareacontrollerroute line and add this?                                                     
  endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "areas",
                    pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=StudentExam}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

Comment: not working i added your code in question see above  i tried this url http://localhost:59958/Student/StudentExam/Index   its ok or not

Comment: can you add here the code snippet of Index action in StudentExam controller?

Comment: Please check i added controller and index page code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a pattern like this for different areas. For student area you add this code snippet:

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "areas",
                    pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=StudentExam}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
);
```

In your controller you have to add annotation of area like this:

```
public class StudentExamController : Controller
  {
    [Area("Student")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
  }
```

Comment: it is for dotnetcore