# C# async / await question - getting "The return type of an async method must be void, Task or Task<T> even though I do return a Task

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I am trying to modify an existing synchronous method in my C# .NET 4.6.1 windows service / console application (can be run either way) to make it asynchronous, due to porting my code to Quartz 3.x, in which the coding style was modified to use asynchronous methods.

I'm puzzled why I'm getting an error in the method below:

```
private async Task ClearDynamicSchedules(int accountID)
{
    log.Debug("Clearing existing schedules for account: " + accountID);

    string group = "AccountID:" + accountID;
    int count = 0;

    var groupMatcher = GroupMatcher<JobKey>.GroupEquals(group);
    var jobKeys = await this.Scheduler.Quartz.GetJobKeys(groupMatcher);
    foreach (var jobKey in jobKeys)
    {
        var detail = this.Scheduler.Quartz.GetJobDetail(jobKey);
        var triggers = await this.Scheduler.Quartz.GetTriggersOfJob(jobKey);
        foreach (ITrigger trigger in triggers)
        {
            await this.Scheduler.Quartz.UnscheduleJob(trigger.Key);
            count++;
        }
    }
    log.Debug("Schedules cleared for account: " + accountID + ", load schedules should follow. " + count.ToString() + " schedules removed");
    return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult<object>(null);
}
```

The error message is on the method title, and says:

> The return type of an async method must be void, Task or Task

I am returning a Task, so I am puzzled why the error still appears.

Comment: The docs say this about the Task.FromResult method: `Returns Task<TResult>` To create a Task object that does not return a value, retrieve the Task object from the CompletedTask property.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.fromresult?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Your returning a completed task with an object as a result, not a Task.  Your error would vanish if you change return type to Task<object> though I’m against this approach you’ve taken.

Comment: Just remove the return line, it isn't needed, the function is technically a "void" function and you are returning a value.

Comment: It's simple `await` returns a `Task` for you. Finally your method is done and nothing needs to be returned.

Comment: Please make sure you haven't declared your own type named `Task`. All the talk about the return here, although correct, is not the source of this error. Returning a Task object would give something like `Since this is an async method, the return expression must be of type 'int' rather than 'Task<int>'`.

Comment: The marked duplicate doesn't answer this. @LasseV.Karlsen has the right idea: that specific error message happens only if you have some other class in your project called `Task`. See [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DhEWiM).

Comment: @Gabriel Luci - Sorry, you're right - the marked duplicate doesn't really answer it, though in reading the marked duplicate I did gain sufficient context to realize the answer even before reading Lasse V. Karlsen's comment. I figured what I had done wasn't typical, and the link did respond to my invalid return statement, so I figured that was maybe enough. In retrospect though I probably should have said 'no' to the duplicate question and requested Lasse V. Karlsen to post his reply as an answer so I could mark it as answer. Sorry!

Answer (score 4):

Normally you have to return whatever you declare the function returns.

```
Task<int> Bar()
{
    return Task.FromResult(1);
}
```

But when you add `async` to a declaration, the return of the Task is added for you by the compiler.

```
async Task Foo1()
{
    //No return needed.
}

async Task<int> Foo2()
{
    return 1; //Compiler converts the int to a Task<int> for you
}
```

So in your example, your function is returning a Task of its own, which interferes with the task the compiler was going to add. In order to return another task you'd have to do something ike this

```
async Task<Task<object>> Foo3()
{
    return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
}
```

...which would be very strange and probably not what you want.

I think in your case you just need to remove the `return` statement and it'll work the way you want it to work.

```
private async Task ClearDynamicSchedules(int accountID)
{
    log.Debug("Clearing existing schedules for account: " + accountID);

    string group = "AccountID:" + accountID;
    int count = 0;

    var groupMatcher = GroupMatcher<JobKey>.GroupEquals(group);
    var jobKeys = await this.Scheduler.Quartz.GetJobKeys(groupMatcher);
    foreach (var jobKey in jobKeys)
    {
        var detail = this.Scheduler.Quartz.GetJobDetail(jobKey);
        var triggers = await this.Scheduler.Quartz.GetTriggersOfJob(jobKey);
        foreach (ITrigger trigger in triggers)
        {
            await this.Scheduler.Quartz.UnscheduleJob(trigger.Key);
            count++;
        }
    }
    log.Debug("Schedules cleared for account: " + accountID + ", load schedules should follow. " + count.ToString() + " schedules removed");
    //No return
}
```

Comment: Although what you're saying may make some tiny bit of  sense and prove your point, there is no point in using `async` without `await`. I am pretty sure the compiler will warn you about this too.

Comment: Thank you very much! I had tried not returning anything as well, and it didn't work, but the issue turned out to be something no one would have guessed... one of the other libraries referenced in my project also defined a Task, so Task was resolving to the wrong type, which caused the error when the method was otherwise "correct".

Answer (score 0):

You can use the generic flavour `Task<T>`. Also, its recommended to have the method prefixed with the word Async for async method. More on the naming convention here:

[Does the use of the "Async" suffix in a method name depend on whether the 'async' modifier is used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15951774/does-the-use-of-the-async-suffix-in-a-method-name-depend-on-whether-the-async)

Since, you are not returning any value which might be relevant to the calling method, there is no point returning null like your method always returns null whether the logic is true or false.